# Google Spreadsheet - Not calculating numbers with space

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to do a calculation of two cells, where one of them contains a number like this: 1 250.

If the number is written like that, and not 1250, then I cannot get the spreadsheet to do any calculations with it. Google suddenly do not treat it as a legit number anymore.

Why not just type 1250 instead of 1 250? 
Well, I am getting the cell values from a html import function.

Any good advice on how to get around this?

Comment: Highlight the column and change the format to something other than what it is now. Then do the same to ensure it is numeric.

Comment: What do you *expect*???  How is "the computer" supposed to "guess" you mean "1250", instead of "1" and "250", or something else entirely???  *You* are responsible for validating input, and *you* are responsible for detecting and correcting any input errors!

Comment: lay off paulsm4, good grief

Comment: The problem isn't with the spreadsheet; it's with your import. Fix the strings and remove the spaces BEFORE they're added to the spreadsheet.

Comment: Paul:well, I thought that Google is pretty much trying to guess my entire days with their services, so I wouldn't consider this question outrageous ;)
Btw, MS Excel have no problems with an identical task.

Blazemonger: I agree, but what if the sources of the data is coming from someone else? In this case I am not the author of the data source

Comment: @paulsm4 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_31-0#Numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
=Substitute(A2," ","")
```

In this formula, A2 is a cell. You are finding any spaces in that cell and then replacing it with a "non-space".

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitute function to transform your number before using it in a formula.  For instance, let's say you wanted to multiple F8 by 2, but F8 may contain spaces.  You would then do:

```
 =substitute(F8, " ","") * 2
```

Comment: My pleasure, although I recommend you accept @Matt's answer, as he beat me to the punch :)

Answer (score 2):

Substitute didn't work form me. But these steps did:

1. Select one or several columns of data
2. Press `Ctrl + H` to get the *"Find and Replace"* dialog
3. Make sure *"Search using regular expressions"* is checked ✅
4. Enter `\s` to the *"Find"* field, and leave *"Replace with"* empty
5. Click on the *"Replace all"* button

Explanation:

`\s` is a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) matching any kind of whitespace character. There may have been some other kind of whitespace in my spreadsheet, not a regular `" "` (space) character, and that's why regex worked for me, while [`SUBSTITUTE()`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en) didn't.

I've also tried the [`REGEXREPLACE(A2, "\s", "")`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en) function, but it didn't seem to to anything in my case.